# Error in knitting shiny in RMarkdown. Error in appshot.shiny.appobj

Tags: shiny, rstudio, r-markdown

I am creating a test page over #RMarkdown and trying to add #Shiny content in it. While knitting to HTML I am receiving the following error.

> Error in appshot.shiny.appobj(list(httpHandler = function (req)  :
>   appshot of Shiny app objects is not yet supported. Calls: 
>   ... in_dir -> do.call ->  -> appshot.shiny.appobj Execution
>   halted

Please help. What are the packages that would be required to run shiny app in #RMarkdown? Or what should be done to successfully run #shiny on #RMarkdown?

Below is my test code.

````
```{r setup, include=TRUE, echo=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(shiny)
```

```{r tabs, echo=FALSE}

shinyApp(

  ui = fluidPage(
tabsetPanel(
        id = 'dataset',
        tabPanel('diamonds', DT::dataTableOutput('mytable1')),
        tabPanel('mtcars', DT::dataTableOutput('mytable2'))
      )
),

server = function(input, output) {
},
  options = list(height = 500)
)
```
````

Answer (score 2):

you need to add to the header of the rmd

```
runtime: shiny
```

Comment: The header of the chunk that the Shiny app is in? That doesn't work for me.

Comment: No, the header of the rmd. Between the output: html_document and the dashes.